# What's the meaning of "Fire up the 50" and "Give 'em a soup tour"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, slang, quotations

They are two quotes of the Riptide Air-cushion Vehicle in the video game "Red Alert 3".

source: https://cnc.fandom.com/wiki/Riptide_ACV

These words are quite simple, but I don't understand the two sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Fire up the 50", uses a synecdoche where "the 50" is a reference to the fact that this vehicle (the Riptide Air-cushion) uses a 50. caliber weapon. So, "fire up" means get it started, get it rolling, and "the 50" refers to either the vehicle or the machine gun.—**Get the vehicle/weapon started**
2. "Give 'em a soup tour" is more difficult, but on the wiki page for the game it lets us know that "soup" is also used in such phrases as "turned into steel soup". My guess here is that "tour" is used in the sense of "a sightseeing experience".—**Let them see/experience what it's like to be turned to soup**